# How parameters should be used in sitk.ReadImage()?

Tags: simpleitk

I am doing N4 bias correction in .nii file in python(Windows).For this I am using SimpleITK.While taking input of the image, I am having issues in reading the file.

Code :

```
 print("N4 bias correction runs.")
 inputImage =sitk.ReadImage("C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii")
 maskImage = sitk.OtsuThreshold(inputImage,0,1,200) 
 sitk.WriteImage(maskImage,"C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1_Mask.nii")
 inputImage = sitk.Cast(inputImage,sitk.sitkFloat32)

 corrector = sitk.N4BiasFieldCorrectionImageFilter();

 output = corrector.Execute(inputImage,maskImage)
 sitk.WriteImage(output,"C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1_Mask.nii")
 print("Finished N4 Bias Field Correction.....")
```

Error :

```
RuntimeError                             
 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-0835d7f75708> in <module>()
      1 
      2 print("N4 bias correction runs.")
----> 3 inputImage = sitk.ReadImage("C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii")
      4 
      5 maskImage = sitk.OtsuThreshold(inputImage,0,1,200)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\SimpleITK\SimpleITK.py in ReadImage(*args)
   8612 
   8613     """
-> 8614     return _SimpleITK.ReadImage(*args)
   8615 class HashImageFilter(ProcessObject):
   8616     """

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ReadImage: C:\Users\dashboard\Miniconda3\conda-bld\simpleitk_1521730316398\work\Code\IO\src\sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:89:
sitk::ERROR: The file "C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use the Unix-style paths, then you need a leading slash, so the file path should be:
    "/C/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii/"

Or you can use Windows-style paths, then it would be:
    "c:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii"

Comment: I am using Windows, single backslash is not working so I tried double blackslash and yes it is working ! Thanks !

Comment: Here it is :  inputImage = sitk.ReadImage("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\Brats18_2013_1_1_t1.nii")

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it working.  I'm not really a Windows guy, so my windows was not quite right.